# Change Firefox address bar behavior

Tags: firefox

In Firefox, when you type `java.util.Scanner` into the address bar, Firefox will attempt to connect to `http://java.util.Scanner`, which is not what I intended.

I have tried disabling `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` to no avail.

I'm looking for a way for Firefox to perform a search using my default search engine when given anything that isn't a valid URL. Specifically in this example, I would like the address bar string `java.util.Scanner` end up at `https://www.google.com/search?q=java.util.scanner` (or whatever my default search is).

Comment: Does this mean if you typed in `google.com` it will also  perform a search and not take you to the website?

Comment: @Dave No, valid URLs in the address bar behave as expected (i.e. `google.com` in the address bar go to Google's homepage), strings are aren't anything like URLs (i.e. `fuzzy bunnies`) perform a search engine search of fuzzy bunnies.

Comment: And how is Firefox supposed to know that java.util.Scanner is not a valid URL? In fact, with ICANN's new domain policies it might be next week. It conforms to DNS RFC's (except for the capital S perhaps). Also, going to a Google search for everything you type without `http://` in front of it is going to be really impractical.

Comment: I suggest that instead of clicking the address bar, you go to the search bar instead (shortcut is CTRL+E) as this will do the search

Comment: @mtak This is behavior I'm seeking as I've gotten used to it from Chrome. As of 39.0.2171.95 is behaves as I describe. I've stopped using it for unrelated reasons and can deal with the lack of it

Comment: I only did a quick Google search, but potentially https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noredirect/

Comment: In the settings of the search engines of the search bar you can also define "keywords" for them. so you can use "g" as keyword and then type "g java.util.Scanner" if you want to look it up on google e.g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In Firefox, when you type java.util.Scanner into the address bar, Firefox will attempt to connect to http://java.util.Scanner, which is not what I intended.

If you add a `'` character before any search term that looks like a url then firefox will perform a normal search.

For example:

```
'java.util.scanner
```

Will end up with the following string in the address bar:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=%27java.util.scanner&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8
```

And the search results will be as expected.